# Exact place to bind and remove events in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I have added an eventListener in `componentWillMount` and removed it in `componentWillUnMount`.

Like this

```
componentWillMount() {
    store.on("onSuccess", this.onSuccess);
}

componentWillUnMount() {
    store.removeListener("onSuccess", this.onSuccess);
}
```

But Component gets loaded in DOM on button click. Actually there is a flag for this component.  Each time I click a button, flag sets true and `componentWillMount` gets called. but when flag is set false, `componentWillUnmount` is not getting called even when component is not present in DOM.

So what happens is, when again I click on button component appears, but I emit an event, the listener is getting triggered twice. I am thinking that is because older component is still present and still listens the event.

So I just want to know, what is the exact place to removeListeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you just have a misprint in `componentWillUnMount()` lifecycle method. It should be `componentWillUnmount()` instead (with lower `m`).

**Additional info:**

In newer versions of `React` `componentWillMount` lifecycle method became legacy (and renamed to `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()`) and will be removed in `React 17`. It's recommended to use `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method for such purposes instead. (see more detailed information about [legacy lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#legacy-lifecycle-methods).

Comment: Can't believe myself? A typo mistake.... and you get headache for 2 days